# Auto Populate multiple text box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is what I really want to achieve. I can Add multiple textbox and auto populate each one. but the code doesn't work.

Model - Where I query the table

```
function __construct(){
    // DATABASE CONNECTION
    $this->db_mlm = $this->load->database('mlm',TRUE);
}

function auto_product(){
//QUERY THE TABLE
$auto = $this->db_mlm->query("SELECT productCode, productName, qty FROM product where qty !=0 and UPPER($type) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%'");
return $auto->result();
  }
}
```

Controller - I don't think the post data initiate to pass the value to model

```
class Compose_product extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->is_logged_in();
}

public function index()
{   

    if(!empty($_POST['type'])){
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
        //AUTO COMPLETE MODEL
        $this->load->model('Autocomplete_product');
        $rows = $this->Autocomplete_product->auto_product();
        $data = array();
        foreach($rows as $row ){
            $name = $row->productCode.'|'.$row->productName.'|'.$row->qty;
            array_push($data, $name);   
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }


    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('compose_product');
    $this->load->view('includes/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');           
}
```

View

```
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
     <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
     <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

AJAX - Please see this code.

```
//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
type = $(this).data('type');

if(type =='productCode' )autoTypeNo=0;
if(type =='productName' )autoTypeNo=1;  

$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost/hq.cni-system.com/compose_product',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[autoTypeNo],
                        value: code[autoTypeNo],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id_arr.split("_");
        $('#itemNo_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
        $('#itemName_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
        $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val(1);
        calculateTotal();
    }               
  });
});
```

Comment: If you console.log(data) in the success segment of your ajax call, do you see the response you expect?